# Overlap of unique Identifiers when trying to pull/expand data

Tags: mysql

```
LoadTableQuery.Qry = @"
SELECT `orders`.`ordID`,
    `orders`.`OrderType`,
    `prt`.`Name`,
    `orders`.`prtID`,
    `orders`.`ReqRef`,
    `orders`.`DateOrdered`,
    `orders`.`orderETA`,
    `orders`.`DateRcvd`,
    `orders`.`Status`,
    `orders`.`ShipCost`,
    `orders`.`Duties`,
    `orders`.`Currency`,
    `orders`.`Conv`,
    `orders`.`Terms`,
    `orders`.`Shipping`,
    `orders`.`BuyerID`,
    `orders`.`ShipTo`,
    `orders`.`Notes2`,
    `orders`.`Notes3`,
    `orders`.`legacyID`,
    `prt`.`Address`,
    `prt`.`City`,
    `prt`.`StateProv`,
    `prt`.`PostalZip`,
    `prt`.`Tel`,
    `prt`.`Contact`,
    `prt`.`Email`,
    `prt`.`OrderTaxPc`
FROM `n2000`.`orders` left join `n2000`.`prt`
on (orders.prtID = prt.prtID)
```

`prtID` is a unique identifier which I'm using to pull the data I need about the party (their name, address, city..). The way it's written above works, accomplishing what I need it to do. getting and inserting the data into my table.

The issue is, I need a SECOND set of party data, based on `orders`.`ShipTo` instead of `orders`.`prtID` . ShipTo is really just a different prtID.

I'd like to be able to just run it again with

```
on (orders.ShipTo = prt.prtID).
```

I've tried using UNION, but that creates a new row, instead of adding columns to my current row. Which is where I'm looking to pull my data from.

The best way to understand it is, I've expanded prtID to add the Name, Address, City.. column data. I'd like to expand ShipTo as well. I don't know how to do that though without simply overwriting the prtID expansion.

---

The solution was actually quite simple. Hope this helps someone else

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGw9o.png)

Comment: The ideal solution should be to have another join in the query. Need to look at table structures to help you better with that. If you do a `UNION ALL`, that should help with duplicated rows.

Comment: You can join with the same table again using a different column to get different data from the same table.

Comment: I added a visual. I tried something like this 

FROM (`n2000`.`orders` left join `n2000`.`prt`
on (orders.prtID = prt.prtID)) left join `n2000`.`prt` on (`orders`.`ShipTo` = `prt`.`prtID`) 

but it didn't work

Comment: Too many parentheses makes it confusing. Try this...`FROM n2000.orders ord left join n2000.prt prt1 on ord.prtID = prt1.prtID left join n2000.prt prt2 on ord.ShipTo = prt2.prtID`

Comment: Didn't work. threw an exception when it failed to find the rowID:  ... System.ArgumentException: 'Find finds a row based on a Sort order, and no Sort order is specified.'

Comment: That's not an error from the query. Are you trying to do something after getting the results that might cause this?

Comment: It's an error in loadtable. I get this specific error always whenever my syntax is wrong. usually it's a missing ` symbol.

Comment: Can you try to run the query in a sql tool to see if you get the desired output and check the correctness of the query?

Comment: I could, but I feel like I'm close to a solution. Looking at my second picture. This creates a second name col' named Name2.

If I could just SET it based on a different on condition it would satisfy my needs. can you see a way to work this?

Comment: I don't think that will give you the correct output. It will also give you multiple rows for each prtId

Comment: it creates a new column actually. called Name2. which is right now populated with the same data as Name. If I could alias `prt` as `prt2` for the version that's matched to ShipTo. I would be done.

Comment: If you do a join using an `OR` then you'll need to aggregate the results at the end using a `GROUP BY`. The correct way to join is the way I had mentioned and then you can use the columns you need from each table.

Comment: I solved it :) I'll post my solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's what I had suggested in my comments.

Comment: sorry for not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was actually quite simple. Alias the different tables and do a double left join

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri4qd.png)